# can someone help me. my code won't show in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am following Mike Dane's React tutorial and for some reason the code is not showing in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

**index.html:**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
const reactContentRoot = document.getElementById("root")

ReactDom.render('hello world', reactContentRoot)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". Also, be careful with tags. You've added [react-native], which is different from [reactjs] and requires a different setup routine.

Answer (score 0):

Things have probably changed slightly since the video you reference was released. `ReactDom.render` is no longer the way to do things.

Always best to give the documentation a read :) https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-2-add-the-script-tags

Anyway here is how it is done now. in your index.js:

```
const reactContentRoot = document.getElementById("root");

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(reactContentRoot);

root.render("hello world");
```

And you are off an running.

Enjoy your learning.

Comment: How can you make that assessment without knowing the version they're running?

Comment: Because ReactDom.render is for version =< 17. The api changed in react 18 as referenced in the documentation link. I know they are using react 18 because it is listed in the url https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am a little late in responding but I appreciate it